# doesn't apply css to dynamic html menu

Tags: css, asp.net, menu, pageload

I have a dynamic menu that is created from database in `Page_Load` event.
When my page is being loaded, for one second or less my page is appeared like below:

[image]

and then:

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

My code behind :

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Database db = new Database();

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string queryMenu =
            "select a.CatId,c.CatName,a.ParentId,b.totalSubCats from ProductCategory as a LEFT OUTER JOIN (select ParentId,count(*) as totalSubCats  from ProductCategory group by ParentId) as b on a.CatId=b.ParentId LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductCategory as c on a.CatId = c.CatId ORDER BY a.CatId";
        SqlCommand smd = new SqlCommand(queryMenu, db.sc);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(smd.ExecuteReader());
        this.createMenu(dt, 0);
    }
}


private void createMenu(DataTable dt, int pID)
{
    LiteralMenu.Text = LiteralMenu.Text + "<ul>";
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["ParentId"]) == pID)
        {
            LiteralMenu.Text = LiteralMenu.Text + "<li><a href='/category/" + dt.Rows[i]["CatId"].ToString() + "'>" +
                dt.Rows[i]["CatName"].ToString() + "</a>";
            if (dt.Rows[i]["totalSubCats"] != DBNull.Value)
                this.createMenu(dt, Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["CatId"]));
            LiteralMenu.Text = LiteralMenu.Text + "</li>";
        }
    }
    LiteralMenu.Text = LiteralMenu.Text + "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: Load your **CSS** before **javascript**, try putting your **CSS** in your `head` and all **javascript** or **jQuery** in the end of your `body`.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay my css file is before js files.

Comment: @MajidBasirati just put your page_load code to understand your scenario well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem before,
I guess, the id or class that you have used in your css file was added with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a neater solution, but whenever I have this sort of issue I set the dropdown stuff to `display: none;` in the CSS and then have JavaScript change it back to `display: block;` (or whatever is desired) on page load. That way you aren't waiting for the JavaScript to execute to hide the content - it's now the opposite.

Comment: As I said, I hide drop-down in css, not in js. (If you see first picture) Any css code doesn't apply to my menu.